# Check if rectangle fits in other rectangle which already contains rectangles

Tags: c#, math, geometry

i want to write a method (or class) which checks, if a given rectangle (rectangleToCheck) fits into another rectangle (outerRectangle) which (maybe) already contains rectangles (innerRectangles). Rearrange and rotate (by 90 dregrees) is allowed.

```
public bool CheckIfFits(Rectangle outerRectangle, IEnumerable<Rectangle> innerRectangles, Rectangle rectangleToCheck)
{
}
```

Example:
[image]

I already have the easy part to check if the area of *outerRectangle* minus the sum of areas of *innerRectangles* is greater or equal to the area of *rectangleToCheck*. But now i'm at the point to get all possible free areas and i have absolutly no clue, how to calculate that.

Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Do not use area.  You want to check if both the width and height of new rectangle is less than original.  Also do 2nd check for 90 degree rotation which is width is less the height and height is less than width.

Comment: You might want to read a few papers about "two-dimensional knapsack problem". The best way to achieve it is using "dynamic programming"

Comment: @jdweng The area is just a precondition. If the area is to small, i don't have to check further, because it can't fit in any way.

Comment: @Bizhan Thanks for the buzzword. I found a few papers about the "knapsack problem".

Comment: The area is an unnecessary step because you still have to test height and width.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
Two approaches **better than brute recursion** exist.

1. "If you are not looking for optimized result and fine with greedy choice kind of results, you can probably sort rectangles by decreasing areas and do follwoing:

start filling rectangle A starting with largest rectangle
After each fill, there will be some space left, fill with the largest rectangle possible in that shape.
If any of the smaller rectangle fits, then okay repeat previous point, else replace the last added rectangle with the smaller rectangle. Do the same until you get your rectangle filled.
You are very likely to get the rectangle filled, only if it is possible, otherwise the problem won't take much time to run for four smaller rectangles."

2."For optimized and a better approach, you can have a look at shape annealing technique to solve geometric knapsack problem. I hope this helps. Thanks."

https://www.quora.com/I-am-looking-for-algorithms-to-solve-a-geometric-knapsack-problem-It-is-given-figure-A-a-rectangular-with-the-rectangular-holes-You-have-to-give-an-answer-Can-you-build-figure-A-using-a-certain-number-of-smaller-rectangles-B1-B2-B3-B4

Explanation about the algorithm and example can be found in the link below, in your case you need to consider height and width instead of weight  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/

Comment: brute-force recursive algorithm happens to be the worst solution to any problem that can be solved otherwise. Also how can you evaluate a placing that *takes minimum space*? rectangles will always take the same amount of space

Comment: @Bizhan Point taken! edited, if you have additional suggestions for edit, please.